# Delete item from a pivot table

Tags: laravel

I try to delete an item form a pivot query , and i'm not sure if i do the right method .

Here my view with some "football stades" for a structure (club)

structure can have many stades and stades have many structures

here my model Stade :

```
public function structures()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Structure');
    }
```

here my model Structure :

```
 public function stades(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Stade');

    }
```

My pivot table is like:

```
structure_id 
stade_id




@foreach($club->stades as $stade)
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{$stade->lb_nom}}</th>
                            <th>{{$stade->adresse_stade}}</th>
                            <th>{{$stade->ville_stade}}</th>
                            <th>{{$stade->cd_post_stade}}</th>
                            <th>{{$stade->tel_stade}}</th>
                            <th>
                                {{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['club.stade.destroy', $club->id , $stade->id ]]) }}
                                {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
                                {{ Form::close() }}


                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

I can insert a new stade to a structure without any problems

```
 public function store(Request $request , $id){

    $stade_structure = new ClubStade;

    $structure =  Structure::findOrFail($id);

    $stade_structure->structure_id = $structure->id;

    $stade_structure->stade_id = $request->input('stade_id');

    $stade_structure->save();

        return back()->with('status', "Un nouveau stade à été ajouté pour votre Club ! ");
    }
```

but now i would like to detach or delete the record from the table . do i need to make a delete function ?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You may pass an array of id's to detach() that you want to delete from the pivot table. like `$stade->structures()->detach([1, 2, 3...])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detach() is what you're looking for:

This will delete item only from pivot table.

If you want to delete relating model then you have to use delete method.
[Click here for more detail](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)

Comment: public function detach($id){

        $stade = Stade::findOrFail($id);

        $stade->structures()->detach();

        return back()->with('status', "Stade supprimé de votre Club");
    }